# Where exactly are new variables located when using Struts 2 tags?

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2

I'm learning to use Struts 2 tags and I have some doubts about where are new variables stored when using some of those tags. For example, when I want to create a new variable in the `action` scope like this:

```
<s:set var="newVar" value="'This is a new string'" />
```

and then I want to get the value of this new variable I can use either:

```
<s:property value="#newVar"/>
```

and also

```
<s:property value="newVar"/>
```

which confuses me because I can't figure where is this new variable stored in. The first `property` tag makes me think it's stored in the *action context map* but outside of the `ValueStack`, and the second `property` tag makes me think it's stored as a new property in the action object, which is placed at the top of the `ValueStack` (whose name doesn't need to be specified when accessing one of its properties)...
I even got to think that maybe the name of the variable given in the tag's attribute `var` allows you to access the variable directly... But then I tried to set another variable, this time in the session scope, like this:

```
<s:set var="sessionVar" scope="session" value="'Another string'">
```

but the only way I can access its value is by:

```
<s:property value="#session.sessionVar"/>
```

but not by:

```
<s:property value="sessionVar">
```

so I discarded the thought that the name of the variable could allow you to access the variable straight away.

Another doubt of the kind is when I use the Struts 2's `action` tag. For example, I have an action class that contains a property called `usersList` (which is a Java `List`). Then I want to call that action within my JSP page with:

```
<s:action name="nameAction" namespace="/" var="actionVar" />
```

which is supposed to place that action object at the top of the `ValueStack`. However, when I want to iterate over the `userList` property in the action object, I need to specify also the name of the variable representing the action preceded by `#` like this:

```
<s:iterator value="#actionVar.userList">
    ...
</s:iterator>
```

So, I don't know exactly where is exactly the action object placed or what is my mistake?

Thanx for your suggestions.

Comment: Do you have any error of accessing those objects?

Comment: No, I don't get any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you close the `<action>` tag like you did:

```
<s:action name="nameAction" namespace="/" var="actionVar" />
```

the action is no longer on the stack, instead it's stored in the value stack "context" (not on the stack itself, but named in the stack's context). If you want to access the action's properties without having to store it then you'd nest it like anything else, think of it as `<s:push>`:

```
<s:action name="nameAction" namespace="/">
  <s:property value="userList"/>
</s:action>
```

IMO the `<s:action>` tag leads to spaghetti code that's difficult to reason about.

The confusion regarding when `#` is necessary was compounded when it was made optional for some, but not all, variables. I forget which version, somewhere during 2.1 or 2.2 IIRC. It is *not* stored in the action; you cannot alter the structure of an action from the view.

`<s:property>` does not automagically search the servlet context scopes. You may, however, use plain old JSP EL to access such things, e.g., `${sessionVar}`. Because of the S2 request wrapper you can also access action properties via JSP EL.

Comment: Thanx for your reply, Dave. Yes, as you said, the action is not in the "value stack" but in what I call "action context" for everything to make sense. The thing is that the Struts 2 official documentation refers the _var_ attribute as the "Name used to reference the value pushed into the Value Stack" which I thougth it was true but now I assume is not correct.

Comment: @Nextor I'd say that's misleading verbiage; can you provide a link? I'll try to fix it up. There are some other docs that need fixing so I'll roll it into that work.

Comment: And the same seems to happen for the **set** tag: the new variable is stored in the "action context" (or "stack context"), not in the "value stack", even the Struts 2 doc says it does. Here are the links: [link](https://struts.apache.org/docs/action.html), [link](https://struts.apache.org/docs/set.html)

Comment: @Nextor The "action context" contains everything; the value stack, the scope maps, etc. `<s:set>` doesn't "push onto the value stack", though; that's an error. I'll discuss terminology w/ the rest of the S2 team and we'll take it from there. Thanks for the input.